# Additon of BLOCKS in BEAMER

Tags: beamer

I have a code that gives a beamer presentation. On the **3rd** slide named **GOALS**, I need to add an **EMPTY BLOCK** like one drawn in the given figure. Similarly I also need help to remove the small **DARK YELLOW part** of the upper block. I am attaching **LATEX CODE**  &  **DESIRED FIGURE**
[image]
[`The text and its font I want to copy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzf9w.jpg)

```
% Copyright 2004 by Till Tantau <tantau@users.sourceforge.net>.
%
% In principle, this file can be redistributed and/or modified under
% the terms of the GNU Public License, version 2.
%
% However, this file is supposed to be a template to be modified
% for your own needs. For this reason, if you use this file as a
% template and not specifically distribute it as part of a another
% package/program, I grant the extra permission to freely copy and
% modify this file as you see fit and even to delete this copyright
% notice. 

\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}

% There are many different themes available for Beamer. A comprehensive
% list with examples is given here:
% http://deic.uab.es/~iblanes/beamer_gallery/index_by_theme.html
% You can uncomment the themes below if you would like to use a different
% one:
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usecolortheme{crane}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\newcommand{\cvec}[1]{{\mathbf #1}}
\newcommand{\rvec}[1]{\vec{\mathbf #1}}
\newcommand{\minor}{{\rm minor}}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\<}{\langle}
\renewcommand{\>}{\rangle}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\rom}[1]{\expandafter\@slowromancap\romannumeral #1@}
\makeatother
\usecolortheme{default}
\renewcommand*{\familydefault}{\rmdefault}

\begin{document}

\title{\LaTeX}

% A subtitle is optional and this may be deleted
\subtitle{Advanced Methodolgy in Mathematics\\
\vspace{5 mm}
Master in Advanced Mathematics}

\author{Amna Alshanbari}
% - Give the names in the same order as the appear in the paper.
% - Use the \inst{?} command only if the authors have different
%   affiliation.
\date{November 25,2014 \\ \includegraphics[width=3cm]{logo}}


%\titlegraphic{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{logo}}

%\pgfdeclareimage[height=0.5cm]{university-logo}{university-logo-filename}
 %\logo{\pgfuseimage{university-logo}}

\subject{Theoretical Computer Science}
% This is only inserted into the PDF information catalog. Can be left
% out. 

% If you have a file called "university-logo-filename.xxx", where xxx
% is a graphic format that can be processed by latex or pdflatex,
% resp., then you can add a logo as follows:

% \pgfdeclareimage[height=0.5cm]{university-logo}{university-logo-filename}
% \logo{\pgfuseimage{university-logo}}

% Delete this, if you do not want the table of contents to pop up at
% the beginning of each subsection:

\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}{Contents}
\begin{block}{}
  \begin{enumerate}
\setbeamertemplate{enumerate items}[circle]
   \item Goals
   \item Columns
\begin{itemize}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[circle]
   \item Text in two columns
   \item Text in three colums
    \end {itemize}
  \item Fundamental Theorem of Calculus
  \item Big Math Expressions \rom{1}
  \item Big Math Expressions \rom{2}
  \item Examples using Ti\textit{k}Z
  \item Examples using  X\textsubscript{Y-pic}
  \item Remarks
  \item Bibliography
\end{enumerate}
\end{block}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Goals}
\begin{block}{}
In this assignment you should make an exact copy of this pdf file,changing your {\color{blue}Name and Surname, today's date} and fixing {\color{blue}several misprints}. I have introduced in different places (writing the words in {\color{purple}purple}).\\
\vspace{1 mm }
Be aware that you are supposed to mimic not only the text, alignments, statements, diagrams and the mathematical\\
 formulas, but also the \textit{font} and {\huge size}, highlighted text, the use of $\backslash$\texttt{pause}, $\backslash$\texttt{onslide}, $\backslash$\texttt{only},$\backslash$\texttt{visible}, etc.
%I have introduced in different places (writing the words in purple 
\end{block}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Second Slide Title}
  \begin{itemize}
  \item {
    First item.
    \pause % The slide will pause after showing the first item
  }
  \item {   
    Second item.
  }
  % You can also specify when the content should appear
  % by using <n->:
  \item<3-> {
    Third item.
  }
  \item<4-> {
    Fourth item.
  }
  % or you can use the \uncover command to reveal general
  % content (not just \items):
  \item<5-> {
    Fifth item. \uncover<6->{Extra text in the fifth item.}
  }
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}{Blocks}
\begin{block}{Block Title}
You can also highlight sections of your presentation in a block, with it's own title
\end{block}
\begin{theorem}
There are separate environments for theorems, examples, definitions and proofs.
\end{theorem}
\begin{block}{}
Here is an example of an example block.
\end{block}
\end{frame}


% Placing a * after \section means it will not show in the
% outline or table of contents.
\section*{Summary}

\begin{frame}{Summary}
  \begin{itemize}
  \item
    The \alert{first main message} of your talk in one or two lines.
  \item
    The \alert{second main message} of your talk in one or two lines.
  \item
    Perhaps a \alert{third message}, but not more than that.
  \end{itemize}

  \begin{itemize}
  \item
    Outlook
    \begin{itemize}
    \item
      Something you haven't solved.
    \item
      Something else you haven't solved.
    \end{itemize}
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame with reduced font size}
%\Fontvi
In this assignment you should make an exact copy of this pdf file,chang-\\ing your Name and Surname, today's date and fixing several misprints.\: \\I have introduced in different places writing the words in purple\\
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame with regular font size}
In this assignment you should make an exact copy of this pdf file,changing your Name and Surname, today's date and fixing several misprints.I have introduced in different places (writing\\ the words in purple
%\Fontvi

\end{frame}





% All of the following is optional and typically not needed. 
\appendix
\section<presentation>*{\appendixname}
\subsection<presentation>*{For Further Reading}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
  \frametitle<presentation>{For Further Reading}

  \begin{thebibliography}{10}

  \beamertemplatebookbibitems
  % Start with overview books.

  \bibitem{Author1990}
    A.~Author.
    \newblock {\em Handbook of Everything}.
    \newblock Some Press, 1990.


  \beamertemplatearticlebibitems
  % Followed by interesting articles. Keep the list short. 

  \bibitem{Someone2000}
    S.~Someone.
    \newblock On this and that.
    \newblock {\em Journal of This and That}, 2(1):50--100,
    2000.
  \end{thebibliography}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Never ever, especially if you are teaching others about TeX, end your lines with double backslashes! Never!

Comment: Search for `postit` in the beamer manual

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{xcolor}
%\usecolortheme{default}
\usecolortheme{crane}
\setbeamercolor{postit}{fg=black,bg=yellow!20}
\renewcommand*{\familydefault}{\rmdefault}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Frame with regular font size}
\begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=1mm,wd=\textwidth,rounded=true,shadow=true]{postit}
In this assignment you should make an exact copy of this pdf file, changing your 
Name and Surname, today's date and fixing several misprints.I have introduced in 
different places (writing the words in \textcolor{purple}{purple}.)

Be aware that you are supposed to mimic not only text, alignments, statements,
diagrams, and the mathematical formulas but also \emph{fonts}, {\Huge size}, 
\alert{highlighted text}, the use of \texttt{\textbackslash pause, \textbackslash 
onslide, \textbackslash only, \textbackslash visible}, etc.
\end{beamercolorbox}
\begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=1mm,wd=\textwidth,rounded=true,shadow=true,ht=3cm]{postit}

\end{beamercolorbox}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]